# In Empire Strikes Back, does anyone directly quote the Godfather?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, quotes

In my mind I can remember Han Solo or Lando saying "he made us an offer we couldn't refuse" in reference to Darth Vader. Did I imagine it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html)'s the script for *The Empire Strikes Back* and there's no quote that's same or similar to what you have mentioned.

You probably did imagine it.

The actual quote by Lando is:

> I had no choice. They arrived right before you did. I'm sorry.

<sup>taken from comment by  nicolallias</sup>

Comment: Precisely, the actual quote is "I had no choice.  They arrived 
right before you did.  I'm sorry."

Comment: The same wording is in the official novelization as well. No offer he couldn't refuse.

Comment: Also, just to be pedantic, the Godfather quote is, "He made him an offer he couldn't refuse", so it still wouldn't be *directly* quoting which the OP asks...

Comment: "Leave the Blaster, take the cannoli."

Comment: "I am altering the deal. Pray I don't alter it any further." also has a mobster-ish vibe to the wording.

Comment: OP might have also been thinking of "That's always been a danger looming like a shadow over everything we've built here.  But things have developed that will insure security. I've just made a deal that will keep the Empire out of here forever."